# zsh: command not found: node in vscode ( MAC OS )

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, zsh

I have installed node LTS (16.15.1) version in my mac machine using `brew` and `nvm`.
Following these steps : [How To Install NVM on macOS with Homebrew](https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew/)

I'm able see node and npm version in terminal, but in vs-code terminal it shows `zsh: command not found: node`.

Comment: How did you set the path?

Comment: yeah, sound like a `PATH` issue to me.

Comment: how to set PATH ?